# SubWCRev.exe in msbuild to find local modifications

Tags: msbuild

i want to execute SubWCRev.exe in msbuild to check for local modifications .if local modifications found then i want to display message on command prompt.
please tell me how can i use this.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using MSBuild `Exec` task you can't get the output, so you'll have to write an MSBuild [custom task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9883dzc.aspx) to do that (Or an [inline task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd722601.aspx) if you are using MSBuild v4).

In that task you'll execute `SubWCRev.exe`, parse the result and set it to an output property.